# JSOUP заменить тег

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup, парсер

Всем привет. Есть необходимость с помощью jsoup заменить тег `<a>` на `<iframe>`, при этом все атрибуты должны быть сохранены. Как это сделать?

Comment: стер теги... заменить тег 'a' на 'iframe'

Comment: за 20 секунд находится [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/530049/17609)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Оправляем в гугл строку

> [jsoup rename element](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=jsoup%20rename%20element)

2. Идём по первой [ссылке](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12475965/3212712)
3. Видим ответ:

   ```
   String html = "<font>fsdfs<font>dfsdf</font>dasdasd</font>";
   Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
   Elements elements = doc.select("font");

   // rename all 'font'-tags to 'span'-tags, will also keep attributs etc.
   elements.tagName("span");

   System.out.println(doc.html());
   ```